# Change paragraph text using select (combo box) input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change all instances the word "blue" in a paragraph to another colour based on combo box input; the colour of the word changes to the corresponding input. Not sure what else to try. You can check my attached code.

```js
document.querySelector(document).ready(function() {
  var button = document.querySelector("button_change");
  document.querySelector(button).click(function()

    {

      var select = document.querySelector("input_color").value;

      var element = document.querySelector(".cow_color");

      document.querySelector(element).html(inputValue);

    });
});
```

```html
<h2>
  <span class="cow_color">Blue</span> Cow by Gelett Burgess (published in The Lark, 1895)
</h2>
<p>
  I never saw a <span class="cow_color">Blue</span> Cow, I never hope to see one; But I can tell you, anyhow, I'd rather see than be one.
</p>
<p>
  Change the cow's color to:
  <select id="input_color">
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Teal">Teal</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button_change">Change!</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You either need an eventListener or an onclick-trigger to run the script.
2. you use `element.querySelectorAll('.class-name')` as selector to select all classes with that class name
3. to apply the changes to all elements you use the `.forEach(el => el.command)` command.

final JS line should be:

`document.querySelectorAll('.cow_color').forEach(el => el.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#input_color').value;);`

```js
function changeColor() {
  var inputValue = document.querySelector('#input_color'),
      cowColor = document.querySelectorAll('.cow_color');
  
  cowColor.forEach(el => el.innerHTML = inputValue.value);
}
```

```html
<h2>
  <span class="cow_color">Blue</span> Cow by Gelett Burgess (published in The Lark, 1895)
</h2>
<p>
  I never saw a <span class="cow_color">Blue</span> Cow, I never hope to see one; But I can tell you, anyhow, I'd rather see than be one.
</p>
<p>
  Change the cow's color to:
  <select id="input_color">
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Teal">Teal</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button_change" onclick="changeColor()">Change!</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Overview

Heres a jquery version

#### Example

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/f6rdLtub/)

#### Explination:

we bind to the button, then on click event, we get the value from the dropdown selection. with that value we loop through all `.cow_color` and assign the color with the value we got previously and also it replaces the Text.

#### Code

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button_change', (element) => {
  let color = $('#input_color').val();
  let spans = $('.cow_color');
  spans.map(function() {
    $(this).css('color', color);
    $(this).html(color);
  });
  return;
});
```

```html
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<h2>
  <span class="cow_color">Blue</span> Cow by Gelett Burgess (published in The Lark, 1895)
</h2>
<p>
  I never saw a <span class="cow_color">Blue</span> Cow, I never hope to see one; But I can tell you, anyhow, I'd rather see than be one.
</p>
<p>
  Change the cow's color to:
  <select id="input_color">
    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Teal">Teal</option>
  </select>
  <button id="button_change">Change!</button>
</p>
```

Comment: @tacoshy added that Change

Comment: how would I go about making your snippet javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: i'll add an edit.